# Calling a storyboard Asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rectangle in my window. if i move the mouse towards the right corner of the window, i use MouseMove to detect the mouse position and fire an animation called AnimateRight() which translate the rectangle to the right horizontally.

However, during this animation, if the mouse moves to the center of the window, i want the reectangle to stop translating and just stay where it stopped.

How do i do this?

```
private void AnimateRight()
    {

            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();

            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            da.From = 0;

            da.To = 200;

            TransformGroup transGroup = new TransformGroup();
            transGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
            gr.RenderTransform = transGroup;


            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, gr);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].X"));

            sb.AccelerationRatio = 0.8;
            sb.Children.Add(da);
            sb.Begin();

    }
```

Comment: did you try to pause the storyboard?